# Website with ActivexObject in Web Browser Firemonky delphi is not opening

Tags: android, delphi

I need open website.com  and this website contain this **java script** code.

```
var x=new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            x.open("HEAD",document.location,false);
            x.send();
```

This website cannot open on web browser Delphi android mobile.
anyway to open it ?

Answer (score 2):

This website can only work with a browser that supports ActiveX. Typically that means Internet Explorer on Windows. You will not be able to use this site on a mobile browser. This is not even related to Delphi. You'll find that any other browsers on your mobile devices behave the same way.